# Object Variable in a query

Tags: sql, ssis

I am using SSDT 2017 and I am working on a solution that basically gets a full result set from a query into a variable (1 column only: AccountID), and I need to include the values in that object variable in a query, something like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM dbo.account WHERE AccountID IN (" + @AccountIDObjectVariable + ")"
```

I tried with an expression but I get an error, so I am not sure if there's a better way, also I tried a for each loop container logic but since I have millions of record in the object variable I think that's not the best way.

Any idea?

Comment: what's the variable data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work that way. Where "it" is going to be a host of things.

The SSIS data types are primitive types (boolean, date, numbers) or Object. The only supported operations for Object is a null check and enumeration.

SSIS parameterization is only for equality based substitutions. There is no concept of a list data type in SQL so there's no analog in SSIS.

> I have millions of record in the object variable

Even if you converted your list to a string and used string concatenation, the next problem you're going to run into is the string length limit of 4000 characters.

## What is the way?

Let's reset the problem: You have a non-trivial set of identities from a source system. That set of ids needs to be used as the basis for a subsequent extract.

### Is the source of identities and the actual data on the same server

While you can empty the ocean with a teaspoon, it's not the correct tool. Same holds true here. Move the query that identifies the recordset to be extracted into a filter condition for your source.

i.e.
Load dataset into @AccountIDObjectVariable

```
SELECT
    OA.AccountId
FROM
    dbo.OutstandingAccount AS OA;
```

Extract that isn't working

```
"SELECT * FROM dbo.account WHERE AccountID IN (" + @AccountIDObjectVariable + ")"
```

is rewritten as

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.account AS A WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.OutstandingAccount AS OA WHERE OA.AccountID = A.AccountID);
```

There are two reasonable approaches for solving this

### Pull it all

If the source ids list and the source table are of similar orders of magnitude, it might be easier to just bring it all down and use the account id generating query in a Lookup Task. If AccountID exists, then it's the data you want. Yes you pulled more than you wanted but you likely would have burned more cycles and complexity trying to selectively pull what you wanted.

### Push and pull

This approach is going to work for SQL Server and I have no idea about any other database. Well, I suppose Sybase would be the same given database paternity.

Open SSMS and create a global temporary table on the database where dbo.account lives. Do not disconnect from SSMS.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##SO_66961235') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE ##SO_66961235;
END
GO
CREATE TABLE ##SO_66961235
(
    AccountID int NOT NULL
);
```

Modify the Connection manager to set the RetainSameConnection Property to true for the database connection to dbo.account

**Execute SQL Task - Make Temp Table**
Use the connection to the account database and the above query. This will ensure the table exists for future sessions of SSIS to work.

**DataFlow Load IDs**
In the dataflow properties, set DelayValidation to **True**

Use your source query to generate the list of IDs and select the temporary table as the destination. You *might* need to have a second connection manager to this system running and pointed at tempdb, it's been a long time since I've done this. Same rule about RetainSameConnection will hold true though.

When this data flow completes, then we will have a temporary table on the data source server that we can reference.

**Dataflow 2 Get Data**
Again, DelayValidation to true.

Source will be a query

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.account AS A WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ##SO_66961235 AS OA WHERE OA.AccountID = A.AccountID);
```

What's with all the delay validation?

When the SSIS package starts, the *first* thing it does is ensure all the pieces are in place for it to run successfully and not only are the pieces in place, is the shape of the data still the same? A temporary table won't exist when the package starts and the package will fail with VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA error. Setting DelayValidation tells SSIS that it should not worry about checking until the component actually gets the signal to start before it checks metadata. Since we defined the precursor Execute SQL Task to create the table, the validation should succeed.

I used global temporary tables here. You can use local scoped temporary tables but it makes the already fiddly design process much more so. Were it me, I'd have a package parameter controlling a boolean that uses a global temp table for development sessions and local temp table for actual run-time operations but that's beyond the scope of this question.